# Trouble converting on NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an NSMutableArray 'myArray' which contained some customObject 'A', Now I want to convert 'myArray' to tempArray which contained some object which subclass 'A' named as 'B'.
As a property just like follow:

```
NSMutableArray <B *> tempArray;
tempArray = [myArray mutableCopy];
```

But the object in tempArray always is kind of 'A'. I want convert 'A' to 'B', Any suggestion?

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: if you will do tempArray = myArray is always will be Type A not type B, and what is purpose to do this

Comment: Elaborate it more please. Do you want to upcast A objects to its subclass B??

Comment: 'B' has more property  which i want to use.

Comment: if the object instantiated of class `A`, it will not change its type magically to `B`. you can explicitly typecast it, but after the first and second thought is would be pointless if the `B` is subset of `A` then it has all properties, you don't need to downcast it for having access to its parent class's features – so your question makes no sense. what do you want to achieve anyway?

Answer (score 1):

> 'B' has more property which i want to use.

How do you expect this to work? `B` is a child of `A`, it contains more information (the property you wish to use etc.). Where would the data for that property come from?

You need a way to construct a new instance of `B` using (the properties of) an instance of `A` and supplying the extra data a `B` needs. `B` might already have a suitable `init` method, or you may need to write your own code.

Once you have a way to produce a new `B` you can just iterate over your array building a new one, building a new `B` instance for each `A` instance.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you have an immutable array (NSArray) that means you can't add or remove objects, or replace objects with other objects. [myArray mutableCopy] creates an NSMutableArray. It will contain *exactly* the same objects as the immutable array, but you are now free to add or remove or replace objects.

Your declaration NSMutableArray * tempArray does nothing but lie to the compiler. If myArray contained objects of type A*, then tempArray contains the same objects of type A*. You are just lying, so the compiler *believes* they are objects of type B*, but they are not.

There is no way on earth how a compiler could automatically convert an object of some class to an object of a subclass. If the subclass has additional members, for example, how is the compiler going to fill those members? This just cannot work.

If you want to create new objects of type B*, based on objects of type A*, you have to do that by hand, likely using an initialiser like

```
- (instancetype)initWithA:(A*)a;
```

in your B interface. Your code could be for example

```
NSMutableArray <B*> *tempArray = [myArray mutableCopy];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < tempArray.count; ++i) {
    tempArray [i] = [[B alloc] initWithA:tempArray [i]];
}
```

or possibly

```
NSMutableArray <B*> *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (A* a in myArray)
    [tempArray addObject:[[B alloc] initWithA:a]];
```